# Access child object's id in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, parameters

I have a model User, that has_many belongings (a belonging belongs_to a user). I have a show user page that shows a user's info and a list of all his belongings. I added a link to each of a user's belonging to access a show belonging page, this link currently does not work, because I don't know how to access the belonging's id.

Both user and belonging are defined as resources, belonging being not a member of user.

Here is the piece of code:

User show page contains:

```
<% unless @user.belongings.empty? %>
  <table class="belongings" summary="User's objects and services">
    <%= render @belongings %>
  </table>
  <%= will_paginate @belongings %>
<% end %>
```

using this partial:

```
<td class="belongings">
    <span class="id"><strong>Object ID: </strong><%= belonging.id %></span><br/>
    <span class="name"><strong>Name: </strong><%= belonging.name %></span><br/>
    <p>
    <span class="description"><strong>Description: </strong><%= belonging.description %></span>
    </p>
    <span class="price"><strong>Price per week: </strong><%= belonging.price %></span> <br/>
    <span class="caution"><strong>Caution: </strong><%= belonging.caution %></span><br/>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(belonging.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to "Show item", belonging_path %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is how to access the belonging's id in the belonging's controller:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @belonging = @user.belongings.find(params[:id])
    @title = @belonging.name
  end
```

==> :id always refer to the user's id. I have tried using :user_id to access the user, but then I have a "cannot find user without an id" and if I try to access the belonging using :belonging_id, I have "cannot find a belonging without an id" ..

I know this is basic, but I'm new to Rails and I've been searching to understand how to solve this for hours...

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a collection to a partial via the `:collection` option, the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection.

```
<%= render :partial => "belonging", :collection => @belongings %>
```

and given you have `_belonging.html.erb`.

When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial. In this case, the partial is _belonging, and within the _belonging partial, you can refer to belonging to get the instance that is being rendered.

With this, since you have belonging variable available, use it to refer the belonging. In your partial change the line:

```
<%= link_to "Show item", belonging_path %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Show item", belonging_path(belonging.id) %>
```

Now, the `show` action of `belongings_controller.rb` will receive a **id** of **Belonging** not the User.

Comment: Thanks a lot Syed, you saved my day ! I really do appreciate the full explanation you gave, as you may have noticed I was a bit lost and confused !